# Converting a GMP integer to a base N integer

Tags: c++, c, math, biginteger, bignum

GMP allows to print a mpz_t up to base 62, but I want to represent a number into any base N, and for this I first need to generate an array of integers (let us say I will limit myself to base 2 ^ 64), so an array of `unsigned long` might do it.

For example if I want to take any integer and convert it to base 792, I can't put it into a string directly, I have to make an array of integers first.

Is there existing code for this in GMP, like some math of some kind I need to learn about or should I start coding it ?

P.S.
I know it's totally irrelevant to employ the term 'base' while I could use 'linear vector space', so it makes the conversion pointless, but there a lot of symbols in unicode (95,221 in  unicode 3.2), so I could still find a way to represent those with single symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, GMP's functions directly or indirectly call the `mpn` layer - which are documented here:

http://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions.html#Low_002dlevel-Functions

The `mpn_get_str` only supports bases up to 256. So I don't think you can go higher unless you write your own base conversion (which is not trivial at all).

Comment: What so you mean by not trivial ? I don't know if I can convert directly from one base to another without using "native" numbers first.

Comment: I meant that it's not easy to write a base conversion - let alone an efficient one. There's also no known algorithm to efficiently go from one base to another without first going through the native (binary) base. If you really need bases higher than 256, it might be possible to modify the source code of `mpn_get_str` to do so. From what I understand, it's limited to base 256 since it outputs to an `unsigned char` array. Internally, the algorithm probably allows bases up to the size of the `mp_limb_t`.